# react/node MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

thank you in advance for reading this.

Id like to start by saying im completely new to react/node/mongoose and mongoDB, so sorry if I miss something very basic, ive only really been developing in react since christmas on and off, and have now decided to add a node back end to it. I have pretty much everything working, a react form that passes variables to a node backend. The problem im struggling with is when my API decides to try and save something using an atlas hosted mongoDB. I havent always had this issue, when developing this in another node app it seemed to be intermitent until i came off my work VPN and which case it inserted everytime, so i thought great, time to take it into my react project. This is currently what the API looks like (see below, have replaced the username and password in the DB const for obvious reasons but i can assure you these are correct)

```
module.exports = {
  registerUser: async (username, password) => {
    //const User = require("./database/schema/userSchema.js");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      username: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, "a user must have a username"],
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, "a user must have a password"],
      },
    });

    var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

    const DB =
      "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.mh4jhqg.mongodb.net/tehcooky?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    console.log("DB: " + DB);

    mongoose
      .connect(DB, {
        userNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      })
      .then(() => console.log("DB Connection Successful!"))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    var message = "";
    var user = new User({
      username: username,
      password: password,
    
});
    console.log("user object: " + user);
    console.log("attempting to register user");
    await user
      .save()
      .then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc);
        message = "user data send to database";
        console.log("sent to database");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error : ", err);
        message = `error: ${err}`;
      });
    mongoose.disconnect();

    //const response = "nice";
    const response = `message: ${message}, user: ${username}, password: ${password}`;
    return response;
  },
};
```

i have tried resetting my connection, changing my dns, putting model commands later then the db connection and making it await before it continues in most cases. I also have my IP stored in the access place on atlas, as well as the accept all connections from anywhere setting just incase.

Wondering if anyone can help me, im sure that theres some glaring flaws with what ive written as i haven't done really any tidying but as far as i can see everything is fine until it hits the save, which im assuming is a promise that mongoDB takes over, and then possibly its having some kind of authentication issue with trying to actually insert the data? the collection is being hit according to the graphs

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestions, got our solutions architect on a call today and we found a solution, apart from the fact i need to clean up the code and refactor, this is it

```js
module.exports = {
  registerUser: async (username, password) => {
    // const User = require("./database/schema/userSchema.js");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      username: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, "a user must have a username"],
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, "a user must have a password"],
      },
    });

    const User = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
    const message = "";

    console.log("attempting to register user");

    const DB =
      connection string (taken out);
    console.log("DB: " + DB);

    const connection = await mongoose.connect(DB);
    if (!connection) {
      console.log("No connection");
      throw new Error("no connection");
    }
    const user = new User({
      username,
      password,
    });
    const data = await user.save();
    console.log("the data send back by promise is: " + data);
    await mongoose.disconnect();

    // const response = "nice";
    const response = `message: ${message}, user: ${username}, password: ${password}`;
    return response;
  },
};
```